# WCF- Custom username-password authentication for NETTCP duplex service in Console host

Tags: wcf, authentication, console-application, wcf-security, duplex-channel

I was searching about an example of custom userName/Password authentication for nettcp binding in wcf service and host it on a console application but I couldn't find anything. so I stated to write an example for myself.

I got [this](https://derekwill.com/2015/05/11/building-duplex-services-with-wcf/) example and change it to use app.config. so I create this configuration file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="GroceryListDuplexBehaviors">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" 
                                customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="GroceryListDuplexServiceHost.MyValidator, GroceryListDuplexServiceHost"/>
        <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" 
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="localhost"/>

      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="GroceryListDuplexBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>

</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="GroceryListDuplexBehaviors" 
           name="ExampleDuplexServiceLibrary.GroceryListDuplexService">
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9011/WCFServices/" binding="netTcpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="GroceryListDuplexBinding" name="GroceryListDuplexService"
              contract="ExampleDuplexServiceInterface.IGroceryListDuplexService" />
    <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="GroceryListDuplexServiceMex" 
              kind="mexEndpoint" address="http://localhost:9001/WCFServices/mex" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9001/WCFServices/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

so I run the service on my local system and it run successful. then I create a test project and add that service with these configuration file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="certificateEndpointBehavior">
        <clientCredentials>
          <serviceCertificate>
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
          </serviceCertificate>
        </clientCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="GroceryListDuplexService">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9011/WCFServices/" binding="netTcpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="certificateEndpointBehavior"
            bindingConfiguration="GroceryListDuplexService" contract="ServiceReference1.IGroceryListDuplexService"
            name="GroceryListDuplexService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The client run success in local machine but when i run client on a remote machine and want to connect to the service it get error.

The error is `An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See
 the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.` 
and the inner exception is `An error occurred when verifying security for the message.`

My question is How can i create a duplex WCF service with nettcp binding and Custom username/password authentication and hosting it on a console application?

Comment: It looks correct except `dns` setting in the client config. Do you change it to something else when client runs on remote machine? I expect it to contain name of the server. You can also add similar setting in the server config and ensure they contain similar values.

Comment: I changed endpoint address but I don't have any dns server

Comment: `<dns value="..."/>` is used to check if server identity is what you expect. What is the certificate content that you use on the service? You may want to set DNS value to be equal to it. You can try to use `<dns />`. Alternatively, try to use another certificate on the server (with subject different from 'localhost') and then use same subject name on the client.